# Let $T$ be a linear operator, find his diagonal matrix and a base of $P_2$ formed with eigenvectors of T.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:P_2(\mathbb{R}) \to P_2(\mathbb{R})$ be a linear transformation such that:
$$T(x^2)=3$$
$$T(x)=-3x^2 + 2x -1$$
$$T(1)=4x^2 + 4$$

I already found its associated matrix which is :

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & -3 & 4 \\
    0 & 2 & 0 \\
    3 & -1 & 4 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

After finding this matrix, i found the eigenvalues which are: $\lambda_1=-2$,$\lambda_2=2$,$\lambda_3=6$, they are all  different so this matrix is diagonalizable and a diagonal matrix could be:

$$D=\begin{pmatrix}
    -2 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 6 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$.

Now comes the problem, the exercise asks me to find a base of $P_2$ with eigenvectors of $T$.
I already found the eigenvectors of $T$ associated to each eigenvalue and they form this base:

$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
    -2/11 & -2 & 2/3 \\
    16/11 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$
But this base is written as a matrix. How can i write this base but in the form of ''polinomyals''? i dont know if i am making myself clear, sorry in advance.

Comment: Reverse the process that took you from $T(x^2)$, $T(x)$, and $T(1)$ to the matrix $A$.

Comment: so a base of $P_2$ would be formed like this: $B=-2x^2/11 + 11x/16 + 1;-2x^2 + 1: -2x^2/3 + 1$ ?

Comment: i do not understand what you are saying... those are the eigenvectors associated to each eigenvalue. They are linearly independent  thus they form a base of $P_2$, what is wrong with what i did?

Comment: Nevermind there is a mistake in the typo. Thank you!